# How to finish editing in DatePicker on Android TV if we control the remote control

Tags: datepicker, focus, android-tv

I have a dialog that has two labels, a DatePicker, and two Back and Apply buttons. By default, the focus belongs to the "Apply" button. We start editing the DatePicker by pressing the up button on the remote. We have set the date and want to go down to the "Apply" button. But this is not possible, because with DatePicker you can not go to the button, because when you press the "Down" button on the remote, the date changes. I would like that after setting the date, I would press the Enter button on the remote control and focus would be given to the "Apply" button. Is it possible?

[image]

Below is the code of the dialog:

```
public class DateSelector {
    public static void showSubscriptionDateDialog(Context context, long expiredAt, DateSetListener listener) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.DialogTheme);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_subscription_date);
        DatePicker datePicker = dialog.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
        TextView dateLabel = dialog.findViewById(R.id.subscription_date);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(expiredAt);
        AtomicInteger dayForSave = new AtomicInteger();
        dayForSave.set(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
        AtomicInteger monthForSave = new AtomicInteger();
        monthForSave.set(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        AtomicInteger yearForSave = new AtomicInteger();
        yearForSave.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        setDateLabel(yearForSave, monthForSave, dayForSave, dateLabel);
        Button buttonBack = dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_back);
        buttonBack.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            dialog.dismiss();
        });
        Button buttonClear = dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_clear);
        buttonClear.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            calendar.set(yearForSave.get(), monthForSave.get(), dayForSave.get());
            listener.onDateSelected(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            dialog.dismiss();
        });
        datePicker.init(yearForSave.get(), monthForSave.get(), dayForSave.get(),
                (view, year1, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) -> {
                    yearForSave.set(year1);
                    monthForSave.set(monthOfYear);
                    dayForSave.set(dayOfMonth);
                    setDateLabel(yearForSave, monthForSave, dayForSave, dateLabel);
                });
        buttonClear.requestFocus();
        dialog.show();
    }

    private static void setDateLabel(AtomicInteger yearForSave, AtomicInteger monthForSave,
                              AtomicInteger dayForSave, TextView dateLabel) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE, d MMMM, yyyy", locale);
        calendar.set(yearForSave.get(), monthForSave.get(), dayForSave.get());
        String expirationDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        dateLabel.setText(expirationDate);
    }

    public interface DateSetListener {
        void onDateSelected(long expiredAt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this problem. You can hang the listener on the dialog and catch the click of the Apply button. Here is the code that solves this problem:

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener((dialog1, keyCode, event) -> {
            if (buttonApply.hasFocus() || buttonBack.hasFocus()) return false;
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
                    buttonApply.requestFocus();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        });
```